# Add multiple percent to single cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to add a percent to a cell, for example, =d2*.3+d2*.095 as you can see I am trying to add 30% and 9.5%  to the same cell and get the total combined amount?. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You either want to:

1. add 30% of the original value and add 9.5% of the original value, or
2. add 30% of the original value to the cell, then add 9.5% of the new total to the new total, or
3. enter a formula in the cell you are trying to use in the calculation

For 1:

```
=D2*1.395
```

For 2:

```
=(D2*1.3)*1.095
```

For 3:

You can't do that.